# Is it okay to make "OpenZeppelin contracts" a dev dependency in my React app?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, react, openzeppelin, npm

I am trying to reduce the bundle size of a React application. I deploy a smart contract during the project build pipeline. The contract needs to be inside the project folder of the React app so that it can access the contract ABI. So I have this in the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.3.2",
  ...
}
```

If I move this into `devDependencies`, my Solidity smart contract (^0.8.11 in case it matters) still compiles and deploys with `yarn hardhat run path/to/deploy.js`. I'm worried that maybe features from OpenZeppelin might not work correctly though. [Their documentation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts) says to run `$ npm install @openzeppelin/contracts`, without `--save-dev` or `-D`.

I was just wondering, why would they say to make it a non-devDependency if everything works fine as a devDependency?  Perhaps it actually doesn't work as intended, and I just don't see `Ownable` not working. Does anyone know if I can safely place the OpenZeppelin dependency in devDependencies without unforeseen consequences?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

It's probably safe. It depends on how you structured your contract build step, but odds are you'll be fine.

### Long answer

The question really boils down to "what's the difference between `dependencies` and `devDependencies`?" [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/5695018) does a good job at explaining the difference, but I'll highlight the important bits and explain how they relate to your question.

`dependencies` are always installed when you install your package, while `devDependencies` aren't always installed. There are two common cases where `devDependencies` are not installed: (1) when installing your package from an external location (e.g. in another package or remotely), (2) when installing your package (in any case) with `--production` or `NODE_ENV=production` — the production environment variable is often set by frameworks at deployment.

So what does that mean for `@openzeppelin/contracts`? Well, if you are only compiling your contracts locally or if your compilation step only happens as part of your dev tooling then you probably don't need to worry about `devDependencies` not being installed (unless you're doing something funky).  If your contract compilation step is part of your CI/CD, then you *might* need to worry: you should check what environment variables are set; odds are that you still won't have any problems though. If you're compiling you're contracts at runtime on your deployment platform, then you will probably run into issues.

#### But it might not matter (if you're using Webpack or similar)

Check out [this blog post](https://www.matthewburfield.com/do-npm-dependencies-and-dev-dependecies-effect-your-production-build/), `devDependencies` vs `dependencies` will probably not affect the size of your production build. You're probably using Webpack or a similar bundler to build your project, which will automatically ignore any dependencies that aren't actually required at runtime.

Comment: I'm used vite to generate the project, so my bundler is rollup. You're correct; I compared the size of the bundle in both situations. It's exactly the same, and this makes sense. Thanks for your help.